# How to create border only on part of the side edge, or how to simulate it?

Tags: html, css

I think that two images will clarify everything

**Now I have ([jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/17fvAel)):**

[image]

**And I am wondering is it possible to do that:**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `:after` to hide it, crude I know, but works in the latest browsers:

```
#column1:after{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    height:100%;
    width:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPNpy/281/)

Answer (score 1):

Change/add the css:

```
#column1a {
    margin-right: 200px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color:#E3E3E3;
    padding: 5px;
}
#column1a span { background-color: white; display:block;}
```

Alter the html to:

```
<div id="column1a"><span>Ut enim
```

This is only a rough guide so I'll leave it up to you to tidy up.

Answer (score 1):

Give Like this

```
 #Coloumn1{position:absolute}
```

Demo > http://jsfiddle.net/TPNpy/285/

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```css
    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #left-section {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-right: none;
        float: left;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    
    #right-section {
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left-section"></div>
            <div id="right-section"></div>
        </div>
```